# Can mono/xsp with fastcgi handle more then one request?

Tags: nginx, fastcgi, mono

Right now i am using nginx with mono/xsp through fastcgi. I haven't seen any clear answers but can xsp/fastcgi handle multiple request? I have one instance running all my sites. Would i get better performance if i have an instance per site? (this probably would only happen if one instance can handle only one request at a time).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is yes - it supports concurrency. I've got an application (http://www.flithub.com) running on Ubuntu 11.10 with NGINX. There's just one FastCGI process running an ASP.NET MVC 2 application.

I put a blog post about how I checked this: http://www.newredo.com/2012/01/14/nginx-and-mono-concurrency

Hope that helps.

Comment: That is EXACTLY WHAT I DID. Except i first notice by trying two browsers (firefox, chrome). Then i notice if its the same page but different urls (`?a=1 vs ?a=2`) the page wouldnt block as well. I was also freaked out when i saw the two page (same url) blocking

Comment: The blog post does not exist anymore.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve what you need, I've did, using fastcgi-mono-server2 or fastcgi-mono-server4 on nginx (my choice) or lighttpd. mod_mono on apache is also a valid solution.

Comment: Your answer is not clear but someone suggested something to me and i found my answer. I don't need multiple instance and page request are multithreaded. However i was confused and found that when the same ip address (or machine?) request the same url it is blocking.

Comment: Using xsp on windows or on linux?

Comment: i did it on (debian squeeze) linux